# Free GUI framework to create a single exe?

Tags: c++, windows, user-interface, dropbox

I'm looking for free and easy GUI framework that let me create single exe 
without dependency (like .Net framework) and to be not GPL

as a side note .. im using Qt and its great but i have to be LGPL to use it that means lots of fat dlls . is there any alternative?

p.s 
how did the Dropbox client made of? i know its python but how did they build it? py2exe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm looking for free and easy GUI framework that let me create single exe without dependency (like .Net framework) and to be not GPL

There is no such thing. Three most popular frameworks Qt, GTKmm, wxWidgets are LGPL.

However you can link statically and provide full source code that allows user to replace/update the LGPL part you can do this as it confirms to LGPL requirements
(I'm not a lawyer - don't see this as legal advice).

Now .Net - has lots of dependencies they are just pre-installed.

Now I used to distribute programs with Qt, it was very simple, you need very few dll's. In my case there were: QtCore4.dll, QtGUI4.dll and mingwm10.dll (that is just part of mingw and not Qt). It is not such big problem, so even it is not a single exe but it is simple enough.

Otherwise... Use Win32API -- good luck `:-)`!

**Edit:** as it was correctly commented by @vitaut you may even provide compiled objects letting user link the code and replace the Qt version to keep with LGPL requirements.

Comment: He doesn't have to provide the source code when linking with LGPL, object code is enough. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2277165/qt-single-exe-with-lgpl

Answer (score 6):

LGPL != GPL. You don't have to make your code LGPL or even make it open to use the library that is covered by this license. It is clarified in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2277165/qt-single-exe-with-lgpl).

So if LGPL is suitable, then I recommend [gtkmm](http://www.gtkmm.org/en/index.html).
AFAIK you can link statically with it.

Another options is [wxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org/) which has slightly more liberal [license](http://www.wxwidgets.org/about/newlicen.htm).
As stated [here](http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Compiling_WxWidgets_with_MSVC_(2)#Static_Compilation) you can create
"an .exe application that will run on any Windows platform with no external dependencies that need to be supplied by the developer" with it.

Also to let you know that from January 14, 2009, Qt version 4.5 is available under LGPL in addition to GPL and commercial license (see [here](http://qt.nokia.com/about/news/lgpl-license-option-added-to-qt)).

Answer (score 4):

What about Win32++?

- http://win32-framework.sourceforge.net/index.htm
- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/winsdk/framework.aspx

Or [WTL](http://wtl.sourceforge.net/)?

I found [another topic that might interest you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1916701/a-simple-c-framework-for-win32-windows-applications)

Comment: Welcome.  I think, unfortunately, if you need to edit that you'll have to break the links again... but hopefully you'll soon get that 100 rep, or whatever the req is.

Comment: Ok, so i'll don't edit this post : anyway, you formated it perfectly.

Comment: Is WTL still maintained? The last release was ages ago.

Comment: Yes, I think. If you look on the project page, you can see that the last file date of 2009. In addition, the update seems to be every 2 years: one in 2005, one in 2007, one in 2009. The frequency is low, but regular. (http://sourceforge.net/projects/wtl/files/)

Answer (score 0):

Or use
http://smartwin.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Or maybe http://www.ultimatepp.org/

Answer (score -1):

Not specifically C++, but:

[AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/) scripts can be compiled to self-contained executables.

Also consider [Free Pascal](http://www.freepascal.org/) and the [Lazarus IDE](http://www.lazarus.freepascal.org/) which appears to offer the same end-goal.